# C# .NET Core Razor pages appsettings values not accessible

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor

When I set up a .NET Core v3 Razor web application the startup.cs file contains what I should need in order to access settings/values from the appsettings.json file;

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

According to the docs I should then be able to use;

```
Configuration["mysetting:variable"]
```

Anywhere to access it. However I get the build error 'The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context'.

In order to solve this I have manually built the configuration using;

```
ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("mysetting")["variable"]
```

but it's meant to do that already isn't it? I know this has changed in v3 in v2 you did need to build the configuration.

Comment: Where exactly did you tried to use `Configuration["mysetting:variable"]`?  And what does that code look like? i.e. did you have `Configuration` in your constructor?  Also, did you build the Configuration in your `ConfigureServices()` method in your `Startup` class?

Comment: @JosieG.Bigler sorry for my ignorance, New to MVC/MVVM and have been using razor webpages as its closest to my scripting roots. In MS docs for core 3 you dont need to build the Configuration. I can access the Configuration object in the startup modal but no where else (I assumed you would be able to). I have managed to access the configuration object by either duplicating the field and method for IConfiguration in the modal I am working in (ie not startup.cs) or by converting the field in startup to an internal static field `internal static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this `@inject` statement to the top of your razor page:

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Configuration
```

After that, you should be able to access the config settings using this injected field:

```
var mySettingVariable = Configuration["mysetting:variable"];
```